# jQuery scrollTop function not working after ajax call

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, jquery-ui

here is my ajax call... works fine but the scrollTo plugin from Jquery is not positioning the content where I want it to be. below

```
 //this will show the contents of the email body when the list item is clicked.
    jQuery("#list-item-"+username+"").click(function(){

        jQuery(".reply-to-container").hide();
        jQuery("#reply-to-"+username+"").toggle("slide", {direction: 'up'});
        jQuery("#reply-input-"+username+"").val('');
        jQuery(".display-reply-content").html("");
        jQuery("#send-btn-ajax-"+username+"").hide();
        jQuery("#reply-input-"+username+"").hide("slide", {direction: 'up'});


        var myUsername = getUrlVars()['username'];
        var messageID = <?php echo $this->message_id; ?>;
        var dataString = 'messageID='+ messageID + '&friend=' + username + '&myUsername=' + myUsername;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/friends/mark-read/", 
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {    
                jQuery("#mail-icon-"+username+"").replaceWith("<div id='mail-icon-"+username+"' class='ui-icon ui-icon-mail-open mail-closed'>");
                jQuery("#display-reply-"+username+"").css({"display" : "none"}).html(html).fadeIn(2500);
                console.log(jQuery("#display-reply-"+username+"")[0].scrollHeight);
                jQuery("#display-reply-"+username+"").scrollTop(jQuery("#display-reply-"+username+"").scrollHeight);

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        }) 
    })
```

Here is my CSS of the Div

```
.display-reply-content{
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto; 
    }
```

Comment: here is a jsFiddle that i made that clearly shows that it works... http://jsfiddle.net/5pWqJ/

Comment: updated ajax code call to reflect my recent changes... still no luck however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seemed to fix it:

```
jQuery("#display-reply-"+username+"").css({"display" : "none"}).html(html).fadeIn(1500, function() {
                    jQuery("#display-reply-"+username+"").scrollTop(jQuery("#display-reply-"+username+"")[0].scrollHeight);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the position that the content scrolls to the height of the container:

```
var $content = jQuery(".display-reply-content");
$content.scrollTop($content[0].scrollHeight);
```

Try adding an error function to  your AJAX call to handle any errors:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/friends/mark-read/", 
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {    
            //...
        },
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}
...
```

Comment: then you should add a console.log() statement at the begining to check if it's entering the callback. are other portions of the "success" function working?

Comment: the log is clear when I do that... no errors... hmmm. yes everything is working fine... content is coming back as expected.

Comment: the log is clear even though you added something like 
`console.log("test")` ? If so, that would indicate that the callback function is not being executed...

Comment: when I add console.log("test") the console has output of "test"... call back is working

Comment: what if you add one below where the `scrollTop` function is executed? this would test whether or not an unexpected JavaScript error occurred before it reached that statement.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51285/discussion-between-skeryl-and-massimorai)

Comment: sorry, the solution is not working... nor is anything outputting via the console.log() - I just noticed as well that the fadeIn() plugin is not working either... hmmmm

Comment: update: i;ve added the following  console.log($("#display-reply-"+username+"")[0].scrollHeight);  and the console returns the height of my div... it just doesnt set the scrollTop plugin.. urghh

Comment: yes, i've tried multiple ways... the one you included as part of the jsFiddle doesn't work either...

Comment: is there any error on the console? or does it simply fail to scroll the container?